# Getting Spawn error while running storybook

Tags: node.js, angular, storybook

I am getting  `Error: spawn UNKNOWN at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)` when running storybook.
I am using node v18.16.0 and npm 9.5.1.
Getting this error in windows machine without admin access.